# Search only looks in answer text, not question title, but results show the latter

Tags: feature-request, bug, search

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3961546+iron+package+flash shows one result:

[image]

The way the result is presented suggests that the question title is part of it ("A: Meteor image doesn't show up on every pages"). However, that UX is contradicted by searching for a keyword from the question title failing:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3961546+iron+flash+pages produces no results, even though each of the three keywords in the query does appear in the previous search result.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Weird results from search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256321/weird-results-from-search)